# can I provide an alternate /dev folder

Tags: debian, ubuntu, filesystems, kali-linux

I have been trying to get linux run on my android phone which is Android 12
I used andronix and termux to achieve it, but due to Android's limitations which disallow apps from accessing /data folders (and couple of others which includes /dev) I can't access /dev folder of my linux system without rooting my phone so are there any tools or alternate methods by which I can setup a fake /dev folder for my system to make use of?

Extra Info:
I switched between Debian 10, Ubuntu 20 and Kali all had the same issue, when did `ls -al` It showed that I owned the folder but chmod didnt work on the folder nor did chown

Edit:
Screenshots of the what it shows:
[image]
[image]
so help me linux gigachads show this noob some mercy

Comment: What does it mean "didn't work"? Can you tell me the `ls -laZ` output?

Comment: @k-att I have added the screens you asked for

Comment: Try `setenforce Permissive` first.

Comment: @K-att- I tried to use the command but I don't seem to have installed SElinux to get any output, so the obvious output was `command not found` and after installing the module the output was `SElinux is disabled` and a path along with it to it's bin dir

Comment: What is the `getfacl /dev` output?